# JPA @OneToMany @ManyToOne bi-directional, collection always empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, empty-list

I have a problem with my @OneToMany @ManyToOne bi-directional relationship, whenever I query for the collection I get an empty one back. I have read about similar problems posted here on stackoverflow, but unfortunately non have helped me so far.

#### User Model (OneToMany)

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @JsonBackReference
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<EncryptedSnp> encryptedSnps = new HashSet<>();

  protected User() {}

  public Set<EncryptedSnp> getEncryptedSnps() {
    return encryptedSnps;
  }

  public void setEncryptedSnps(Set<EncryptedSnp> encryptedSnps) {
    this.encryptedSnps = encryptedSnps;
  }

  @Transient
  public void addEncryptedSnp(EncryptedSnp encryptedSnp) {
    this.encryptedSnps.add(encryptedSnp);
    if (encryptedSnp.getOwner() != this) {
      encryptedSnp.setOwner(this);
    }
  }

  // ..
  // some other non-relevant or straightforward property fields, getters, and setters.
}
```

#### EncryptedSnp Model (ManyToOne)

```
@Entity
public class EncryptedSnp {

  private long id;
  private User owner;
  private byte[] value;

  protected EncryptedSnp() {}

  public EncryptedSnp(BigInteger value, User owner) {
    this.value = value.toByteArray();
    this.owner = owner;
  }

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "encrypted_snp_id")
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @JsonManagedReference
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
  public User getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }

  @Column(name = "snp_encrypted", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "blob")
  public byte[] getRawValue() {
    return rawValue;
  }

  public void setOwner(User owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
  }

  // ..
  // some other non-relevant or straightforward property fields, getters, and setters.
}
```

#### Population of the relationship

```
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Transactional
public void addSnps() {
  User snpTestUser = userRepo.findByUsername("snp_test");
  Assert.notNull(snpTestUser);

  EncryptedSnp encryptedSnpA = new EncryptedSnp(getRandomBigInteger(), snpTestUser);
  EncryptedSnp encryptedSnpB = new EncryptedSnp(getRandomBigInteger(), snpTestUser);
  EncryptedSnp encryptedSnpC = new EncryptedSnp(getRandomBigInteger(), snpTestUser);

  snpTestUser.addEncryptedSnp(encryptedSnpA);
  snpTestUser.addEncryptedSnp(encryptedSnpB);
  snpTestUser.addEncryptedSnp(encryptedSnpC);

  userRepo.save(snpTestUser);
}
```

#### Testing

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "user/snp_test/snps", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Set<EncryptedSnp> getEncryptedSnps() {
  User snpTestUser = userRepo.findByUsername("snp_test");
  Assert.notNull(snpTestUser);

  // size is always 0
  Assert.isTrue(user.getEncryptedSnps().size() > 0);

  // irrelevant
}
```

---

PS: 'mysql> select owner_id from encrypted_snp' returns 3 rows with the correct owner_id:

```
+----------+
| owner_id |
+----------+
|        3 |
|        3 |
|        3 |
+----------+
```

---

I hope I have included enough information to clarify my problem.
Basically, my problem is that {user}.getEncryptedSnps() always returns an empty collection.

Comment: Where is that "Population of the relationship" part called? In unit test's `setUp()`/`@Before`?

Comment: With the @Bean CommandLineRunner

Comment: ever tried to turn on some kind of sql logging to see what's the sql issued? Usually this give you enough hints to find out what happened

Comment: Yes I have "Hibernate: select encrypteds0_.owner_id as owner_id3_3_0_, encrypteds0_.encrypted_snp_id as encrypte1_3_0_, encrypteds0_.encrypted_snp_id as encrypte1_3_1_, encrypteds0_.owner_id as owner_id3_3_1_, encrypteds0_.snp_encrypted as snp_enc$
2_3_1_ from encrypted_snp encrypteds0_ where encrypteds0_.owner_id=?"

Comment: I cannot see any obvious thing from what you quoted that can make thing fail.  Try these 1. use tools like jdbcDsLog to check what is the parameter bounded to the sql.  2. Run the very same SQL in the DB. 3. add some logging to check whether the `encrypted_snp` SQL is run when `userRepo.findByUsername(..)` (i.e. caused by eager fetch), or when `user.getEncryptedSnps().size()` (by lazy fetch )

Comment: and, are you sure that the `getEncryptedSnps()` is really run in its own transaction?  i.e. you won't have an transaction opened, and inserted something, and have the transaction 'reused' in `getEncryptedSnps()` (which may cause unexpected problem as it may fetch stuff from 1st level cache)

Comment: hm... one more issue: the generated sql seems strange. column `owner_id` and `encrypted_snp_id` appeared twice, which seems abnormal based on your current mapping

Comment: @AdrianShum I think it is run in its own transaction, i'm quite sure. I have put all the logic in 1 single method in a @transactional annotated concrete class just to be sure. And I'm calling it from my rest controller with only the annotation '@RequestMapping'. `Set<EncryptedSnp> encryptedSnps = userService.findUserEncryptedSnpsByToken(token);`, returned collection is still empty. ---

Any idea what would cause the double generated `owner_id and `encrypted_snp_id`, or possible ways to solve it?

Comment: I have tried using bidirectional `@OneToMany @ManyToOne` relationship, I have tried using unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship, and I have have tried using a `@OneToMany @JoinTable`. All created correct tables in my MySql database. But when queried, User always returns an empty collection. ----- _ps: User does return a non-empty collection of Roles, which has a bidirectional `@ManyToMany @ManyToMany` relationship_